# Eat the Chocolate Bar

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art

I have a chocolate bar and I need help eating it so you'll be writing a program just to do that.

### Explanation

The first line is the input. Examples are separated by an empty line.

```
7
   ____
 __|__|
|__|__|
|__|__|
|__|__|

6
_______
|__|__|
|__|__|
|__|__|

5
   ____
 __|__|
|__|__|
|__|__|

0


1
   ____
   |__|
```

### Spec

Hopefully the examples clearly specify this challenge but to avoid any possible confusion, here's a spec:

You can have a single optional trailing/leading whitespace

An input of `0` is an empty output.

If the input is even, the top rows looks like:

```
_______
|__|__|
```

If it's odd, the top row is:

```
   ____
   |__|
```

If it's odd and greater than 1, the top rows are:

```
  ____
__|__|
```

---

The following rows are:

```
|__|__|
```

until the number of instances of `|__|` is the same as the input

Comment: What's the output for input `1`? Does input of `0` need to be supported?

Comment: @Doorknob yes, I've updated the challenge

Comment: 1. Can we submit a function? 2. Can we take input from STDIN/function arguments? 3. Do we have to output ONE or ALL itterations?

Comment: @YoYoYonnY yes, [by default you can (this link answers your second question too)](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2447/40695). I'm not sure what you mean by iterations. Take a look at the examples, that's all you have to output

Comment: Are leading blank lines allowed?

Comment: @Neil Check second line of spec ;) "You can have a single optional trailing/leading whitespace"

Comment: @Downgoat Oh, with itterations I ment if you should output all chocolate bars from 1 to n or only chocolate bar n.

Comment: @YoYoYonnY just chocolate bar n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Pyth, 55 bytes

```
K"|__|"IQ>7<*3%Q2r"3 7_"9?tQjb+XW%Q2J+KtKZd*/tQ2]J+*3dK
```

[Try it online.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%22%7C__%7C%22IQ%3E7%3C%2a3%25Q2r%223+7_%229%3FtQjb%2BXW%25Q2J%2BKtKZd%2a%2FtQ2%5DJ%2B%2a3dK&input=7&test_suite_input=5%0A6%0A1%0A0&debug=0) [Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=K%22%7C__%7C%22IQ%3E7%3C%2a3%25Q2r%223+7_%229%3FtQjb%2BXW%25Q2J%2BKtKZd%2a%2FtQ2%5DJ%2B%2a3dK&input=7&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=5%0A6%0A1%0A0&debug=0)

This is really quick and dirty, written on my phone. Will get to more golfing later.

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, 101 bytes

Haskell has never been great for code golfing...

```
b="\n|__|__|"
h="   ____\n "
f 1=h++"  |__|"
f 2="_______"++b
f 3=h++"__|__|"++b
f n=f(n-2)++b
f _=""
```

Comment: It depends on how you look at it. Java > Python > Haskell > GolfLang. I use python ;)

Comment: @JAtkin Well look at my [PHP answer](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/71311/43587), then you see what's like **worst**

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript ES6, 80 bytes

```
x=>(x%2?`   ____
 ${x<2?"  ":"__"}|__|`:x?"_______":"")+`
|__|__|`.repeat(x/2)
```

Uses the same technique as my Japt answer, and is surprisingly not much longer...

Answer (score 1):

## Japt, <s>60</s> 57 bytes

```
U%2?[S³'_²²RSU¥1?S²:'_²"|__|"]¬:U?'_p7 :P +"
|__|__|"pU/2
```

Just a basic answer. Can probably be improved. [Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt?v=master&code=VSUyP1OzKydfsrIrIgoge1WlMT9TsjonX7J9fF9ffCI6VT8nX3A3IDpQICsiCnxfX3xfX3wicFUvMg==&input=Nw==)

Answer (score 1):

## C, <strike>104</strike> 102 bytes

```
f(x){x?x%2?printf("   ____\n%3s|__|\n",x<2?"":"__"):puts("_______"):0;for(x/=2;x>0;x--)puts("|__|__|");}
```

<strike>Maybe I can use some printf trickery to improve this...</strike>
Apparently I can

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 134 chars

```
<?$i=$argv[1];if($i>0){echo($i%2===0?"_______\n|__":"   ____\n".($i>1?"___":"   "))."|__|\n";echo str_repeat("|__|__|\n",($i-1)/2);}?>
```

Notes:

- PHP was not built for code golfing
- I sure had FUN making this snippet
- It throws an error if argv is undefined
- Any help to short it is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

## , 53 chars / 67 bytes

```
ï%2?`   ⟮__⟯Ⅰ
 ⦃ï<2?⍞  :⍞Ⅰ⦄|Ⅰ|`:ï?⍘_ď7:⬯⦄
|Ⅰ|Ⅰ|`ď ï/2
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=1&code=%C3%AF%252%3F%60%20%20%20%E2%9F%AE__%E2%9F%AF%E2%85%A0%0A%20%E2%A6%83%C3%AF%3C2%3F%E2%8D%9E%20%20%3A%E2%8D%9E%E2%85%A0%E2%A6%84%7C%E2%85%A0%7C%60%3A%C3%AF%3F%E2%8D%98_%C4%8F7%3A%E2%AC%AF%E2%A6%84%0A%7C%E2%85%A0%7C%E2%85%A0%7C%60%C4%8F%20%C3%AF%2F2)</kbd>

This is quite similar to the Javascript ES6 answer, even though I found it independently. Explanation to come when I finish golfing.

Answer (score 1):

## Retina, 69 bytes

```
r`(1?)1
$1__|__|¶
^__(?=\D{5}$)

^.
$0____¶ $0
^\D

^1
___
 ?1
|
```

Takes input in unary.

[Try it online here.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=cmAoMT8pMQokMV9ffF9ffMK2Cl5fXyg_PVxEezV9JCkKICAKXi4KJDBfX19fwrYgJDAKXlxECiAgIApeMQpfX18KID8xCnw&input=MTExMTE)